# How to have minimum Email Downtime when switching web host?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, domain, migration

I have my domain and hosting in godaddy. My emails are in Google mail.
I want to switch to Bluehost.

I assume my MX records needs to change...right?

If yes, how do I ensure there is minimum downtime for my emails.

I want my emails to remain in Google mail.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assume my MX records needs to change...right?

Wrong.

> I want my emails to remain in Google mail.

Then don't touch your MX records.

If you're only moving your website then modify the DNS records that pertain to your website. Leave all of your other DNS records alone.

Comment: And if you're changing DNS providers, set up the MX records in *both* of them before the move.